# Can't Omit props on conditional type that need to returns never because of infer - how to?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typing

I'm trying to take advantage of react typings to implements (for learning purpuse) a view framework.
Everything is well and dandy except when trying to mix a `conditional type` with the `Omit` type (to showcase it package `@types/react` is needed):

```
import {DetailedHTMLFactory, ReactHTML} from 'react'

type Tags = keyof ReactHTML

type ReactPropsFrom<Tag extends Tags> =
  ReactHTML[Tag] extends DetailedHTMLFactory<infer P, any> ? P : never
```

At this point I do have the properties for an `HTMLElement` according to react definitions by using (for anchors) `ReactPropsFrom<'a'>`.
What is left to do is to remove the react specific properties. Let's define some of them:

```
type ReactSpecificProps =         |
  'defaultChecked'                |
  'defaultValue'                  |
  'suppressHydrationWarning'      |
  'suppressContentEditableWarning'
```

And the `Omit` type

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
```

If i do `Omit<ReactPropsFrom<'a'>, ReactSpecificProps>` everything is fine and i do have in the resulting type all properties I want.

But if i do a more generic approach like so:

```
type Props<Tag extends Tags> = Omit<ReactPropsFrom<Tag>, ReactSpecificProps>
```

I end up with this error

```
// type ReactSpecificProps = "defaultChecked" |...
// Type '"defaultChecked"' is not assignable to type 'keyof ReactPropsFrom<Tag>'.
// Type '"defaultChecked"' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

I do understands it as `ReactPropsFrom` might returns `never` (even if it will never be the case as the generic passed always extends `Tags`), and in that eventuality the type checker break. But as I understands why I can't figure a way to avoid the issue.

Naively I hopped something like:

```
type Props<Tag extends Tags> = Omit<ReactPropsFrom<Tag>!, ReactSpecificProps>
```

with the bang `!` operator (as I know it will never be a `never`) but it can't be used on type definition (?).
Any clue ?

Thanks in advance
Seb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through a lot of trouble to convince the compiler that `ReactPropsFrom<Tag>` indeed contains `ReactSpecificProps` but I would advise against it. The `Omit` type that is coming in 3.5 does not constrain `K` to be a `keyof T` ([PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30552/files) and the [declination to add the constraint](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30825)). So the solution is to just remove the constraint on `K` and it will all work.

For completeness, this is what convincing the compiler would take (at least what I came up with, there may be shorter ways):

```
type Props<Tag extends Tags> = ReactPropsFrom<Tag> extends infer U ?
    [U] extends [Partial<Record<ReactSpecificProps, any>>] ? Omit<U, ReactSpecificProps> : never: never;
```

Comment: thank you very much ;) Just as a quick note didn't get what the last line of code u did had is for ? could you please explain it's purpuse ? tx in advance

Comment: @zedryas It was my attempt at getting things to work with the constraint. Basically I put `ReactPropsFrom<Tag>` in the type variable `U`. Then I check it extends `Partial<Record<ReactSpecificProps, any>>`. This will make the compiler think that on the true branch `U` has the properties in `ReactSpecificProps` and thus `keyof U` will include `ReactSpecificProps`